# TFS Analysis Rebuild Error: column does not contain valid bindings to data and cannot be processed

Tags: tfs, process, ssas, analysis, olap

I am having an issue on my TFS 2010 instance. After a rebuild in the Reporting Tab of TFS I am not getting an error when the Cube full sync happenings. So it looks like the warehouse build happens successfully, but the analysis services build does not. Here is the error.

> [Full Analysis Database Sync]:  AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType=Full,
>   needCubeSchemaUpdate=True. 
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WarehouseException: TF221122: An error
>   occurred running job Full Analysis Database Sync for team project
>   collection or Team Foundation server TEAM FOUNDATION. 
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WarehouseException: Failed to Process
>   Analysis Database 'Tfs_Analysis'. 
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WarehouseException: Error (Data
>   mining): In the **'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource Structure' structure, the
>   'BuildSK' column does not contain valid bindings to data and cannot be
>   processed.**
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.ExecuteXmla(String
>   finalXmla) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.ProcessOlap(AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType
>   processingType, WarehouseChanges warehouseChanges, Boolean
>   lastProcessingFailed, Boolean cubeSchemaUpdateNeeded)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.ProcessOlap(AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType
>   processingType, WarehouseChanges warehouseChanges, Boolean
>   lastProcessingFailed, Boolean cubeSchemaUpdateNeeded) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.AnalysisDatabaseSyncJobExtension.RunInternal(TeamFoundationRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseJobExtension.Run(TeamFoundationRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Any help would be really appreciated,

I have tried rebuilding and looking to see what structure that might be causing this. I have actually changed anything in any of the mining cubes etc so don't know why this has started happening.

---

**UPDATE !!!!**
I have gotten the incremental sync to work by

1. Switching off the Analysis
2. Disabling all of the Warehouse sync jobs.
3. 1 by 1 enabling all of the Warehouse jobs and running them Starting
4. the analysis jobs again 5 Running the incremental sync.

So it seems to me like it may be to do with a lock of some kind. I havent tried the full sync yet as I am a little gun shy and have a presentation on the reports in the morning.

---

**UPDATE !!!!**
The full analysis database sync has happened over night without any issues.

So the steps above should work where locks are not allowing schema changes.
Dave